# Unity Collab: What happens if I go back to a previous version of the project and make a new commit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, commit, collaboration, revert

I am using Unity 2017.2.0f3 and am currently working on the most updated version of my project.

However the changes I am working on wont be in the latest version of my app once the updates are published, so I'm going to have to go back to a previous build of the project from about a week ago. If I go back, make changes to that version of the project and commit them to Unity collab, what happens?

Do the newly pushed changes become the top commit of the collab hierarchy or do they change the commit that I went back to?

For example:
If the most recent commit in the collab hierarchy is #57 and I go back to the commit #52. If I make changes and publish them, will it become a new commit as #58 or will it change commit #52, the one I am currently on?

Thanks.

Comment: In Unity Collab, I am not sure.. But in Git it would create revision #58.. I think what you're looking for, though, is to create a "branch" and keep your master in tact. Not sure if Unity Collab has that functionality, but as far as I can tell it's just a glorified VCS so it should.

Comment: Nah, right now unity collab doesnt have branching